# Alter schema of Access 2013 database with linked table

Tags: schema, ms-access, database-link, inheritance

I'm trying to change the schema of an Access 2013 table. I want to lengthen some of the text fields. When I change the schema and try to save I get dialog with `Operation is not supported for this type of object`, and a note that `This property cannot be modified in linked tables.` That makes sense. So I go to the relationships and try to delete one of the links. This gives me the error: `You can't delete a relationship inherited from a linked database`.

I don't know of any "linked databases" (I didn't create the database). Is there a way I can figure out what/where these might be?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: It's been quite a while, but I think what happened was that I found there WERE linked tables. I just wasn't looking in the right place. Sorry I can't be more help. Also, just thought I'd let you know it's considered more appropriate to put questions/comments as comments to the question, rather than as an answer.